# Java SE 8 Base64 class: encoding of byte[] parameter

Tags: java, encoding, base64, java-8

Background: I'm working with the java.util.Base64 class that's new with Java 1.8.

In the documentation, it specifies that the encodeToString takes a byte array (there are some other options, but byte[] is the one I'm using). However, the doc doesn't specify how the byte array needs to be encoded. Here's my functional code:

```
import java.util.Base64;
import java.util.Base64.Encoder;
public class Test64 {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        try{
            System.out.println(print64("This should be base64"));
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static String print64(String test) throws Exception {
        String test64 = "";
        byte[] testBytes = test.getBytes("US-ASCII");
        Base64.Encoder encoder64 = Base64.getUrlEncoder();
        test64 = encoder64.encodeToString(testBytes);
        return test64;
    }
}
```

The question I have is whether the Base64 encodeToString will accept a byte[] with ANY encoding. I've tried US-ASCII and UTF-8, and those both work, but I'm hoping for a general conclusion.

[Link to Javadoc for Base64.Encoder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.Encoder.html#encodeToString-byte:A-)

Comment: Base64 is a _general_ conversion between _any_ bytes and readable ASCII characters.  Encoding is irrelevant.

Comment: Remember, base64 is also used to encode images, sound files, etc. - it doesn't even consider its input to be an "encoded string" in any form.

Comment: If you already have a String (text) then you don't need base 64. The reason to use base 64 is to encode *any binary* to a String. Sometimes you see base 64 encoding to bytes; in that case US ASCII (or compatible, such as Latin or UTF-8) is assumed. The reason is probably that a Java `char` takes 2 bytes instead of one, so it's more efficient that way.

Comment: @Maarten-Bodewes, I actually needed to encode it because I'm testing the creation of an access key for an API that's based off a Client ID and a Secret Key.

Comment: @RealSkeptic That is a tidbit of additional information that I didn't know before, and I'll bear that in mind.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The documentation does not specify an encoding, so any `byte[]` data will work. Base64 conversion is numerical, not character-oriented, so whoever interprets the Base64 number will have to know what it means. So as long as *your* documentation is clear how to interpret the bytes, you could use the Base64 string for any data serialization.